# django filter order by duplicated times

Tags: python, django

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

And queryset will be..:

```
query = Product.objects.filter(Q(name__contains="a") | Q(name__contains="c")).annotate(
            duplicated_times=some_function).order_by('duplicated_times')
```

In django, Can I make queryset that is ordered by 'how many times matched with filter()'s Q object'?

For example,

| pk | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa |
| 2 | cc |
| 3 | acc |
| 4 | abbc |
| 5 | aaawwc |

In this case,

queryset's name should be ordered like: acc, abbc, aaawwc, aaa, cc

First, annotation's `duplicated_times` option are applied and then `pk` are applied

: acc, abbc, aaawwc has 'a' and 'c' so that it matched filter 2 times, so It is ordered before and aaa and cc is matched filter 1 times therefore it ordered after.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `F` to iteratively increment the duplicated_times for each letter

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When, F

qs = Product.objects.annotate(duplicated_times=Value(0, IntegerField()))
for c in 'ac': # or 'abcde'
     qs = qs.annotate(duplicated_times=Case(When(name__contains=c, then=F('duplicated_times')+1),default=F('duplicated_times')))
qs = qs.filter(duplicated_times__gte=1).order_by('duplicated_times')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) and [`When`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when) to annotate conditionally:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When


contains_a = Q(name__contains="a")
contains_c = Q(name__contains="c")

Product.objects.filter(
    contains_a | contains_c
).annotate(
    duplicated_times=Case(
        When(contains_a & contains_c, then=Value(2)),
        When(contains_a | contains_c, then=Value(1)),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).order_by('duplicated_times')
```

Comment: Thank you, But if contains_ Q object is dynamically, How can I solve it? My Questions's case, contains_a and contains_c -> total 2 cases so that Value(2) and Value(1) and Value(0) are enough, but If contains_a, b, c, d, e -> so total 5 cases.. then Value(5)~Value(0) are needed. Is there any other good way?

Comment: @touchingtwist You can try something like `functools.reduce(operator.add,[Case(When(contains_dynamic then=Value(1)), default=Value(0), output_field=IntegerField()) for contains_dynamic in some_list])` to add an amount of dynamically generated When objects and annotate that (not tested, you might have to make some adjustments) (Note you would need to import `functools` and `operator` for this snippet)